# How to open SQL Server 2012 using run prompt

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012.

How should I specify whether I have to open SSMS 2008 R2 or SSMS 2012 using run prompt when I run SSMS? Let's say for now I have to open SSMS 2012 using the RUN Prompt.

Can somebody please help me on how should I open it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356410/open-sql-server-2012-from-command-prompt/35356797#35356797)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So... on my machine that has both 2008 R2 and 2012 on the same machine, the 2008 R2 management studio exe is here:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"

And the 2012 management studio exe is here:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"

Start -> Run and either of these paths opens up the correct management studio version.

Comment: answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356410/open-sql-server-2012-from-command-prompt/35356797#35356797)

Comment: I run "ssms"  (without the double quotes) from the command line either at the Powershell window or at the Command Prompt window.