# Open SQL Server 2012 From Command Prompt

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, command, sql-server-2014

I have installed SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2014.

Now when I run **SSMS** it always opens SQL Server 2008.

What to do same for SQL Server 2012?

Any shortcut key or command to run from command prompt like `SSMS`?

Please guide me.

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219758/how-to-open-sql-server-2012-using-run-prompt

Comment: Maybe this will help you: [How to open SQL Server 2012 using run prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219758/how-to-open-sql-server-2012-using-run-prompt)

Comment: @nishz -checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219758/how-to-open-sql-server-2012-using-run-prompt) but it just shows whole path to open and I want short cut command.

Comment: @J19 - checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219758/how-to-open-sql-server-2012-using-run-prompt) but it just shows whole path to open and I want short cut command.

Comment: You may create desktop shorcut using this path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It is so simple.

Just create desktop short cut and copy that file to `C:\Windows\`

**For example:**

Create short cut named as on desktop `SQL Server Management Studio` Now simply copy it to your `C:\Windows` path and rename it to `SSMS12` and now from command prompt simply type ***SSMS12*** -

*It will open SQL Server 2012.*